# What happens if we query the MongoDB database in the reverse order of compound index?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

I have the following index

```
Origin.SN_1_timestamp.milliseconds_-1_error_1
```

And I am running the following query

```
db.getCollection("error").aggregate([
{
   "$match":{
      "$and":[
         {
            "error":{
               "$ne":"No Error"
            }
         },
         {
            "timestamp.milliseconds":{
               "$gte":1617561000000
            }
         },
         {
            "timestamp.milliseconds":{
               "$lte":1617627557579
            }
         },
         {
            "Origin.SN":{
               "$in":[
                  "4090",
                  "4080"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
},
{
   "$group":{
      "_id":"$error",
      "count":{
         "$sum":1
      }
   }
},
{
   "$project":{
      "_id":0,
      "count":"$count",
      "error":"$_id"
   }
},
{
   "$sort":{
      "count":-1
   }
},
{
   "$limit":1
}
])
```

You can see that the order of the composite index is reversed in the query. Even though this query uses the above index in IXSCAN. Is there any performance loss in this?
Do I need to create another compound index in reverse order for a better performance?

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/indexes/ the index is used in the $match stage, I would say you don't loose anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think the performance is not affected by the order of the index but you can explain the query and check the execution time:

**[Return Information on Aggregation Pipeline Operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#return-information-on-aggregation-pipeline-operation)**